# minecraft help with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I make teams with command blocks how do I make the command blocks divide up the teams evenly. Another thing is how do I make it check if there's one team alive.

Example:
Blue and red

Blue is dead so then it says red won! How do I do this plz help

One more question is I have to add players to the score board how can I make it so when you join that world it adds you

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#section_1

Answer (score -1):

this is how i would do the first part.
i would first make a command block which sets everyone's team to a dummy team eg. white. then i would have two command-blocks which where connected in a circuit so that they would be powered one after the other, not at the same time. one would have this command in it:
/scoreboard teams join red @p[team=white]
and the other:
/scoreboard teams join blue @p[team=white]
i would also have another command-block as the kill switch so that once everone has a team the two command blocks will stop trying to add people to teams. the command would be
/testfor @a[team=white]
if a comparator is put next to the command-block an output signal will be outputted untill there is no more people without a team.